# code to handle multiple possible collection types in exteral library versions

Tags: java, collections

I am having a problem with a plugin I maintain, in that, in the next version of our app, a collection I need to access from the plugin changes type from a Hashset to an ArrayList.

What I need is to have a single jar for my plugin, which is able to access the collection in the main app, regardless of the version/collection type.

currently if i compile my plugin against V1 (with the Hashset)  the plugin will load on both V1 and V2 but hang when trying to access that collection on V2

And if i compile my plugin against V2 (with the ArrayList) the plugin will load on both V1 and V2 but hang when trying to access that collection on V1

I was able to work around this issue using reflection.
I'm not sure if its the best or fastest way to do this, but it seems to work fine for now...

```
        List<MainPurpose> listOfMps = new ArrayList<MainPurpose>();
        try {

            Method getMps = cs.getContact().getClass().getMethod("getMainPurposes", (Class<?>[]) null);

            if (getMps.getReturnType().isAssignableFrom(Set.class)) {
                Set<MainPurpose> mps = (Set<MainPurpose>) getMps.invoke(cs.getContact(), (Object[]) null);
                listOfMps.addAll(mps);
            } else if (getMps.getReturnType().isAssignableFrom(List.class)) {
                List<MainPurpose> mps = (List<MainPurpose>) getMps.invoke(cs.getContact(), (Object[]) null);
                listOfMps.addAll(mps);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {}
```

Comment: Just some thoughts.  Both HashSet and ArrayList implement the Collection interface.  If you are able to do everything you need to  through the Collection interface, you should treat the collection you get as a Collection instead of a more specific type.  If you can't do this, you can use RTTI (instanceof) to determine the type of collection you have and then cast it accordingly to access the additional methods you need.

Comment: Thanks Michael,
I tried doing that, but even running code to check if the collection is null will hang the server if its the "other" type of collection from what I compiled against